# Timezone added with type="xs:dateTime"

Tags: xml, xsd

When I fill my date field with **28/12/12 08:51:51** and generate an XML file, I get the output **2028-12-12T08:51:51+00:00**. In my XSD file, the type of this field is set as `xs:dateTime`.

The problem is that I only want the Date and Time, and not the time zone. So the output should be **2028-12-12T08:51:51**

Does anybody know where this format is set?

Comment: There are two aspects here: the [XML Schema definition for dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) specifies that the timezone is always allowed for dateTime (and defaults to UTC when not specified). That means your output is valid. Without knowing what tools you use to generate your XML it is impossible to suggest how to configure it to output a timestamp in UTC directly without explicitly adding timezone information. Can you include your code which generates the XML?

Answer (score 1):

Use the pattern as

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss
```

Do this way:-

```
<xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:dateTime">
    <xsd:pattern value="\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: Is this a valid way of representing dates in xsd/xml? Do xml parsers support this?